# self.tableView reloadData doesnt reload UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've been trying to reload my UITableView but to no avail. The code for my viewWillAppear looks like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh  target:self action:@selector(refresh)] autorelease];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The code for my refresh method:

```
-(void)refresh{
    NSLog(@"refreshing UITableView!");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Check that you connected your table view to this property in your XIB file.

Comment: I can display items in the UITableView correctly, as well as use the DidSelectRowAtIndexPath properly. Thats why I'm not sure whats wrong.

Comment: It's possible. I'm still suggesting you to check that your `tableView` property is properly connected to UITableView in your interface XIB file. Do `NSLog(@"%@", self.tableView);` in your `viewWillAppear:` method. If I'm right, it'll be `nil`.

Comment: Its not nil. NSLog(@"Self.tableView is %@", self.tableView); This is the result :

Comment: Self.tableView is <UITableView: 0x5028200; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x4b37420>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, to get an updated list, it was necessary to call the viewdidLoad method again, in addition to the self.tableView reloaddata.

Answer (score 1):

Think the reason is you loosing pointer to your UITableView. Make sure that you UITableView @property is strong (retain) and check maybe you receiving memory warning and all your IBOutlets removing. Before you made reloadData try to:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.tableView);
```

make sure that it's not nil.