# image doesn't change when navigating back

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I read the similar problems and solutions regarding this issue, but it didn't help me. Let's say, I've got 3 UIViewControlers app.

1. At view #2 I placed a picture (.png) red/green (on/off). An int getting retrieved from db, if 1=green else red. It works fine for me.
2. At view #3, I am using UISwitcher to switch the int to values 1 or 0. It also doing well.

The problem. When I am pushing back to view #2 from #3, the picture stays unchanged. And only after pushing to view #1 and back to view #2, I'm getting the image changed.

The data getting retrieved in `- (void)viewDidLoad method`.

What I tried to do meanwhile:

Have added method `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Also I tried to call database method in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`.

Alas, it doesn't help.

Thank you for reading this and helping me.

Comment: can you show the screen shot and explain. it makes me confuse..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the **view 2 register to get notification** for int value changed..and in **view 3 ..when you change int..post the notification using [NSNotification defaultcenter]**

1) **In viewDidLoad of View 2**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(intChanged) name:@"Int Changed" object:nil];
```

2) **In Dealloc of view 2**

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

3) **In view 3 ..when you change int after that put this line**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Int Changed" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

In the end..intChanged method(in view 2) will be called when int value is changed in view 3 **make sure you define a method intChanged in view 2**

Comment: Oops... I am just learning to fly. Can you show me some example/tutorial how to do it?

Comment: I use the customviewcell. Think it should be implemented somewhere in ItemsCustomViewCell.m?

Comment: Ok, you've answered to my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, by the way, thank you for NSNotifications tutorial. That's the useful thing it is.

Comment: NotificationCenter is not necessary here. I managed it by adding -viewDidLoad to -viewWillAppear method. Now it works fine. Link who gave me this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090203/self-tableview-reloaddata-doesnt-reload-uitableview.